# Generating WSDL Proxy for external web service

Tags: web-services, wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to configure wsdl proxy in WSO2 ESB. It is not allowing the following WSDL URL.

https://secure-ausomxapa.crmondemand.com/OnDemand/user/Opportunity.wsdl?WSDLOBJ=Opportunity&WSDLTYPE=CUSTOM&XSDOnly=N&ECBS=Y

I am checking " Publish Same Service Contract" check box while creating. But its throwing ERROR - RPCMessageReceiver com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected chara
cter '=' (code 61); expected a semi-colon after the reference for entity 'WSDLTYPE'

But the above url is correct and it opens correctly by giving user name and password.

I have encoded the above WSDL URL, but its not allowing me to even. Please suggest me what should be the problem with this URL.

Thanks&Regards,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

Download the particular wsdl to your local file system and provide the wsdl path for the "wsdl uri" option like;

```
file:E:/releases/wso2esb-4.0.3/repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl
```